# Android Hawk Object Type not persisting

Tags: android, object, kotlin, types

I want to save a multi-layer HashMap with Hawk for Android Kotlin.
When getting the values from Hawk only the type of the first layer persists,
everything else shows up as String or LinkedTreeMap in the debugger.

```
val subscribedMap = Hawk.get("HawkKey",HashMap<ChannelType, HashMap<Long, DoctorObject>>())
Hawk.put(HawkKeys().subscribedDoctors, subscribedMap)
subscribedMap = Hawk.get("HawkKey",HashMap<ChannelType, HashMap<Long, DoctorObject>>())
```

[image]

In this example only the types of the first HashMap and its contents persists.
The rest is either a String or LinkedTreeMap.